# How to redirect my Google Cloud Run domain to the subdomain "www"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I've two domain mappings in Google Cloud Run:

- domain.com
- [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

The domains are coming from another provider. How can I redirect my domain.com traffic to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) with Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by the domains are coming from another provider, as in if the domain is registered elsewhere or if you have a webserver with another cloud that you want to reverse proxy to your google cloud.

On a possibly unrelated note, as long as you own the domain, you should be able to create a DNS record in Google Cloud without transferring domain ownership.

As for redirecting to the URL I'm assuming you can either perform it at the webserver or use a load balancer.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-redirects-classic